# Pivot only only value and select the remaining without pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like so

```
OutputID    |       Name        |   Value   |
---------------------------------------------
15417       |   Material code   |   ABC123  |
15417       |   Chemical Name   |   ABCdef  |
15417       |   BatchNo         |   BID213  |
15417       |   Container no    |   12      |
15417       |   Notrequired1    |   xxx     |
15417       |   Notrequired2    |   yyy     |
```

Result required

```
OutputID    |   BatchNo     |       Name        |   Value   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
15417       |   BID213      |   Material code   |   ABC123  |
15417       |   BID213      |   Chemical Name   |   ABCdef  |
15417       |   BID213      |   Container no    |   12      |
```

Basically have to select OutputID, Name and Value where Name in Material Code, Chemical Name, Container No and pivot only the BatchNo. The problem i am having is I can either get the pivot working or select the name and value.  I am unable to do both.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

What I have tried so far.

### Shows only the pivoted values

```
Select Outputid, [BatchNo]
from
(
    select outputid, name, value from ##temp_table_unpacked
    where name in ('Material Bar Code','Chemical Name','Container No')
)
AS S
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Value]) FOR [Name] IN([BatchNo])
) As P;
```

### Getting an error (Dont not know Name and value)

```
Select Outputid, [BatchNo], Name, Value
from
(
    select outputid, name, value from ##temp_table_unpacked
    where name in ('Material Bar Code','Chemical Name','Container No')
)
AS S
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Value]) FOR [Name] IN([BatchNo])
) As P;
```

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to do what you want:

```
select tt.outputid, tt.batchno, tt.name, tt.value
from (select tt.*,
             max(case when name = 'BatchNo' then value end) over (partition by outputid) as batchno
      from ##temp_table_unpacked tt
     ) tt
where name in ('Material Bar Code', 'Chemical Name', 'Container No');
```